# Scraping movie scripts failing on small subset

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm working on scraping the lord of the rings movie scripts from this website [here](http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/). Each script is broken up across multiple pages that look like [this](http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/fellowshipofthering1to4.php)

I can get the info I need for a single page with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url_success <- "http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/fellowshipofthering1to4.php"

success <- read_html(url_success) %>%
  html_elements("#AutoNumber1") %>%
  html_table()

summary(success)
     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 2      tbl_df list
```

This works for all Fellowship of the Ring pages, and all Return of the King pages. It also works for Two Towers pages covering scenes 57 to 66. However, any other Two Towers page (scenes 1-56) does not return the same result

```
url_fail <- "http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/thetwotowers1to4.php"

fail <- read_html(url_fail) %>%
  html_elements("#AutoNumber1") %>%
  html_table()

summary(fail)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   list   list
```

I've inspected the pages in Chrome, and the failing pages appear to have the same structure as the succeeding ones, including the 'AutoNumber1' table. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with xpath. Perhaps ill-formed html (page doesn't seem too spec compliant)

```r
library(rvest)

url_fail <- "http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/thetwotowers1to4.php"

fail <- read_html(url_fail) %>%
  html_elements( xpath = '//*[@id="AutoNumber1"]') %>% 
  html_table()
fail
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 139 × 2
#>    X1                                                                      X2   
#>    <chr>                                                                   <chr>
#>  1 "Scene 1 ~ The Foundations of Stone\r\n\r\n\r\nThe movie opens as the … "Sce…
#>  2 "GANDALF VOICE OVER:"                                                   "You…
#>  3 "FRODO VOICE OVER:"                                                     "Gan…
#>  4 "GANDALF VOICE OVER:"                                                   "I a…
#>  5 "The scene changes to \r\n    inside Moria.  Gandalf is on the Bridge … "The…
#>  6 "GANDALF:"                                                              "You…
#>  7 "Gandalf slams down his staff onto the Bridge, \r\ncausing it to crack… "Gan…
#>  8 "BOROMIR :"                                                             "(ho…
#>  9 "FRODO:"                                                                "Gan…
#> 10 "GANDALF:"                                                              "Fly…
#> # … with 129 more rows
```

Comment: Perfect, confirmed that works for all the pages that had an issue. Did you use SelectorGadget to find the xpath?

Comment: chrome inspector (devtools)  right click on html node >  copy > xpath